# Link to resized media file

Tags: media, images

I have a WordPress website with existing content and images. Currently, images in posts link to the original media file. I’d like to modify this, such that they link to a resized version of the image (e.g., max 2000x2000 px). Preferably, this should be done by some filter that is applied when rendering the page, so I don’t have to edit the existing links in my posts.

E.g., I want this:

```
<a href="/wp-content/uploads/file.jpg"><img ... /></a>
```

to be converted into this:

```
<a href="/wp-content/uploads/file-2000x1500.jpg"><img ... /></a>
```

Does anyone know how this could be done (using code or some plugin)?

One thing that makes it challenging, is that the resized image don’t have a constant size (e.g., 2000x2000 px). Because I want the images to be soft proportional cropped, they can get a different size. (E.g., a 4000x3000 px image would be resized to 2000x1500 px.)

Comment: can you tell me what the code in your theme php file looks like?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get_the_post_thumbnail_url` explained [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions//)

So, the code would be

`<a href="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID, array (2000, 1500) ) ?>" >....... </a>`